# Difference between two cons

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, cons

What is the difference between how `cons` works on the following two items:

```
(cons 1 '(2))
; (1 2)
(cons 1 2)
; (1 . 2)
```

Both evaluate `pair?` to true, so I'm curious how the two are different.

Does one produce:

```
 --------
| 1 | 2 | 
 -------
```

And the other produces:

```
 --------        --------
| 1 | -> |       | 2 | X |  
 -------         -------
```

Or what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: If you are using Racket, you might want to look at [sdraw](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sdraw/index.html) which will make pictures which show you the difference.

Comment: yes, but in reverse order. the first picture goes with the last code snippet. (just to be super clear for any onlookers)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in how `cons` works in both cases.

The `cons` is the same. Anything produced by `cons` causes `pair?` to return `true`. Simple as that.

The two things that you `cons` together are different between the two code snippets.

In the second snippet, `(cons 1 2)`, it is two numbers. Eschewing any inclinations toward efficiency of representation and being interested only in conceptual correctness, we regard it as creating

```
        ---------
        | * | * |
        ---------
          |   |
          v   v
          1   2
```

The first snippet, `(cons 1 '(2))`, uses a number `1` and an object created by `'(2)`:

```
        ---------
        | * | * |
        ---------
          |   |
          v   v
          1   ---------
              | * | * |
              ---------
                |   |
                v   v
                2   NIL
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how a *proper* list is defined in Scheme. A proper list is created by `cons`ing elements, where the `cdr` part is either another `cons` cell or the empty list `'()`. The first example in the question is a proper list:

```
(cons 1 '(2))
(cons 1 (cons 2 '())) ; this is the same as above
=> '(1 2)
```

Of course we can also create arbitrary `cons` cells that don't follow the rule. The second example in the question demonstrates this, it's a `cons` cell where the `cdr` part is *not* another `cons` cell or the empty list, hence it's not a proper list:

```
(cons 1 2)
=> '(1 . 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A proper list is always terminated with NIL. I.e., the first code example produces two cons-cells, one within the other, and the innermost is nil-terminated. The second example however doesn't follow the rules for standard lists, as it is just a single cons-cell with two non-nil values.

```
(cons 1 '(2)) 
CLISP> (1 2) ; This list is actually (cons 1 (cons 2 NIL))

(cons 1 (cons 2 NIL))
CLISP> (1 2) ; Same as above
```

However, is you leave NIL out, the REPL will indicate that with a dot.

```
(cons 1 2) ; this cons-cell is not terminated by NIL
CLISP> (1 . 2)

(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 4))) ; A longer example
CLISP> (1 2 3 . 4) ; Notice the dot to indicate last element is non-nil.
```